# Laravel encryption and display

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5.8

I have an object called Secret in which I want the two fields 'secret_title' and 'secret_text' to be encrypted. When a user logs in I then want to display a list of their secrets in a table. I am using setters and getters in the Secret class to encrypt and decrypt the information, however when I go to print the secret_title and secret_text in the view it is still encrypted. Here is my object:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption;

class Secret extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'secret_title',
        'secret_text',
  ];

  public function getSecretTitleAttribute()
  {
    return Crypt::decrypt($this->attributes['secret_title']);
  }

  public function getSecretTextAttribute()
  {
    return Crypt::decrypt($this->attributes['secret_text']);
  }

  public function setSecretTitleAttribute($value)
  {
    $this->attributes['secret_title'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
  }

  public function setSecretTextAttribute($value)
  {
    $this->attributes['secret_text'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
  }

}
```

In the controller I use:

```
public function showUserSecrets()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $secrets = DB::table('secrets')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
        return view('secret.show', compact('secrets'));
    }
```

And in my view I have:

```
    @foreach ($secrets as $secret)
     <tr>
         <td>{{ $secret->id }}</td>
         <td>{{ $secret->secret_title }}</td>
         <td>{{ $secret->created_at }}</td>
         <td><a href="{{ route('secret.show', $secret->id) }}" class="button">View</a></td>
    </tr>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: Hm, could be that you already have a field called `secret_text` which it's showing, try renaming your `getSecretTextAttribute` to something else like `getDecryptedTextAttribute`

Comment: the point of setters and getters is to set and get the fields in the object. from my understanding that means when a new object is created (set) they should encrypt the values and when i want to print (get) decrypt them

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether the functions in question are even called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are not being loaded into your `Secret` model, so the decryption attributes are never being used.

Replace:

```php
$secrets = DB::table('secrets')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

With:

```php
use App\Secret;

// ...

$secrets = Secret::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```